# How to delete all files in a folder that don't match some names

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

Let's say I have a folder with 80 localizations. Since I do speak only two languages, I do not need the remaining 78. Of course I could type `del /S /F /Q` for every single one of them.

But I wonder if there's a way to specify file names that are to stay, and run a `for` command for every file in a directory. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most painless way would be to give a distinguishing attribute to those 2 files:
`attrib +R english`
`attrib +R otherlang`
then delete every file that doesn't have that attribute:
`del /A:-R *.*`
Then you can clear the attributes if you wish.